# JSF Controller ignores @RolesAllowed annotation

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, cdi

I have a JSF controller that is Named and SessionScoped like this

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SomeController {
...
```

adding @RolesAllowed or @DenyAll to the controller has no effect. When this controller invokes EJBs that have the @RolesAllowed annotation, it works properly on those bean calls.

I am using jsf 2.2 and deploying my application to Wildfy 8.1

Comment: JSF has only one controller which is `FacesServlet`. All other managed beans you create and use in your application are essentially models. They are not said to be controllers. You can use those annotations by turning managed beans into EJBs but it is not required after all. On the web tier, page-level declarative security should suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `@RolesAllowed` and `@DenyAll` are active on EJB not on CDI Managed Bean. Try to turn your controller to a CDI session bean.

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
@Stateful
public class SomeController {
...
}
```

You should be able to add security annotation on it because you'll have a component having EJB and CDI features.