# TomEE: Set up login (via JSF) to support @RolesAllowed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee, jaas, openejb

For some reason I got completely lost to get @RoleasAllowed to work in TomEE. I've got a nicely working webapp on TomEE 8.0.8. I have set up a custom form authentication like this:

```
 @CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition(
        loginToContinue = @LoginToContinue(
                loginPage = "/ui/login.xhtml",
                errorPage = "",
                useForwardToLogin = true
            )
  )

@ApplicationScoped
@FacesConfig(version = FacesConfig.Version.JSF_2_3)
public class FacesVersionConfiguration {
}
```

The Login page invokes the login() method of my LoginBean:

```
public String login() {
       // snipped..
        getHttpRequestFromFacesContext().login(userName, password);
      // the getter simply returns the HttpServletRequest
    }
```

This will login the user and calls to SecurityContext.isCallerInRole("testRole") will return true. (The same is true for calling EJBContext.isCallerInRole("testRole")).However using a @RolesAllowed("testRole") annotation on EJB methods wil always end in:

```
javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: Unauthorized Access by Principal Denied
    org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:189)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:265)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:260)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:89)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:349)
```

During my reseach I found: [JSF Controller ignores @RolesAllowed annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772240/jsf-controller-ignores-rolesallowed-annotation) which caused me to configure TomEE to use JAAS by adding

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm" appName="PropertiesLogin"
       userClassNames="org.apache.openejb.core.security.jaas.UserPrincipal"
       roleClassNames="org.apache.openejb.core.security.jaas.GroupPrincipal">
</Realm>
```

to the server.xml. However, this didn't solve the problem, still methods annotated with @RolesAllowed throw javax.ejb.EJBAccessExceptions, althought SecurityContext.isCallerInRole() succeeds.

What would be the correct way to set up this in TomEE? I already browsed through the TomEE examples but I couldn't find a complete example that really sets up TomEE for login via JSF (custom form based) to result in working @RolesAllowed EJB access.
What did I miss? I really don't what to fall back to programmatic role checking.

Is there a way to find out what openejb is actually doing inside the EJB Proxy? Why are all 'my' checks positive, but the role checking of openejb results is a unauthorized access?

Comment: "Is there a way to find out what openejb is actually doing ": Use a debugger and step trough.

Comment: Right, but debugging openjeb would be a major project. I found that StatlessContainer.invoke() uses: 
this.securityService.isCallerAuthorized(callMethod, type);
which obviously returns false in my case. However, as SecurityService is an interface, I can't find out, why it comes to this result.

Comment: Actually debugging isn't that easy as the problem resides in an the gernated EJB proxy. How would I proceed to debug a compile time proxy..?